403 error with CSRF when accesing Django login by axios
  await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/get_csrf_token/").then((res)=>{
    console.log(res.data.csrf_token);
    axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN";
    axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "csrftoken";
    axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    axios.post('http://localhost:8000/login/',{
      username:'admin',
      password:'Kv79NExi'
      
    }, {
      headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-CSRFToken': res.data.csrf_token,
      }
    })
    .then((response) => {
      log("response login",response.data);
    });
  });

I am trying to access django login from command line script(jest) not browser, however it shows the error like this,
<p>Reason given for failure:</p>\n' +
  '    <pre>\n' +
  '    CSRF cookie not set.\n' +
  '    </pre>\n' +

It returns 403 error, it looks like sending csrf_token correctly.
Where am I wrong?
Ran all test suites matching /TopPage/i.

node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^
AxiosError {
  message: 'Request failed with status code 403',
  name: 'AxiosError',
  code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST',
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [ 'xhr', 'http', 'fetch' ],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'csrftoken',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-CSRFTOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    env: {
      FormData: [Function: FormData] {
        LINE_BREAK: '\r\n',
        DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE: 'application/octet-stream'
      },
      Blob: [class Blob]
    },
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: Object [AxiosHeaders] {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-CSRFToken': '9aSiDra8P3LzU0hMlSFZ9yqX5fllDySQljBRyHM6jjSYfuZ1BWrCUF9blkElzl1v',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/1.7.9',
      'Content-Length': '42',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, compress, deflate, br'
    },
    withCredentials: true,
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/login/',
    data: '{"username":"admin","password":"Kv79NExi"}'
  },
  request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      abort: [Function (anonymous)],
      aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
      connect: [Function (anonymous)],
      error: [Function (anonymous)],
      socket: [Function (anonymous)],
      timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
      finish: [Function: requestOnFinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 7,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    destroyed: false,
    _last: true,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: false,
    maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
    _defaultKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    strictContentLength: false,
    _contentLength: '42',
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _headerSent: true,
    _closed: false,
    socket: <ref *2> Socket {
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'localhost',
      _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
      _readableState: ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
        length: 0,
        pipes: [],
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        constructed: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        emitClose: false,
        autoDestroy: true,
        destroyed: false,
        errored: null,
        closed: false,
        closeEmitted: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        awaitDrainWriters: null,
        multiAwaitDrain: false,
        readingMore: false,
        dataEmitted: true,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null,
        [Symbol(kPaused)]: false
      },
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {
        end: [Function: onReadableStreamEnd],
        free: [Function: onFree],
        close: [ [Function: onClose], [Function: socketCloseListener] ],
        timeout: [Function: onTimeout],
        agentRemove: [Function: onRemove],
        error: [Function: socketErrorListener],
        finish: [Function: bound onceWrapper] { listener: [Function: destroy] }
      },
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        finalCalled: true,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: true,
        ended: true,
        finished: false,
        destroyed: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        afterWriteTickInfo: null,
        buffered: [],
        bufferedIndex: 0,
        allBuffers: true,
        allNoop: true,
        pendingcb: 1,
        constructed: true,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        emitClose: false,
        autoDestroy: true,
        errored: null,
        closed: false,
        closeEmitted: false,
        [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
      },
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: null,
      _server: null,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 969,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: TCP {
        reading: true,
        onconnection: null,
        [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *2]
      },
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: true,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: true,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 60,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
    },
    _header: 'POST /login/ HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
      'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
      'Content-Type: application/json\r\n' +
      'X-CSRFToken: 9aSiDra8P3LzU0hMlSFZ9yqX5fllDySQljBRyHM6jjSYfuZ1BWrCUF9blkElzl1v\r\n' +
      'User-Agent: axios/1.7.9\r\n' +
      'Content-Length: 42\r\n' +
      'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
      'Host: localhost:8000\r\n' +
      'Connection: close\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
    _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
    agent: Agent {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {
        free: [Function (anonymous)],
        newListener: [Function: maybeEnableKeylog]
      },
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 80,
      protocol: 'http:',
      options: [Object: null prototype] { noDelay: true, path: null },
      requests: [Object: null prototype] {},
      sockets: [Object: null prototype] {
        'localhost:8000:': [
          <ref *2> Socket {
            connecting: false,
            _hadError: false,
            _parent: null,
            _host: 'localhost',
            _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
            _readableState: [ReadableState],
            _events: [Object: null prototype],
            _eventsCount: 7,
            _maxListeners: undefined,
            _writableState: [WritableState],
            allowHalfOpen: false,
            _sockname: null,
            _pendingData: null,
            _pendingEncoding: '',
            server: null,
            _server: null,
            parser: null,
            _httpMessage: [Circular *1],
            [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 969,
            [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TCP],
            [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
            [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
            [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
            [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
            [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
            [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
            [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: true,
            [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: true,
            [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 60,
            [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
            [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
          }
        ]
      },
      freeSockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: false,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      scheduling: 'lifo',
      maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
      totalSocketCount: 1,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'POST',
    maxHeaderSize: undefined,
    insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
    path: '/login/',
    _ended: true,
    res: IncomingMessage {
      _readableState: ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
        length: 0,
        pipes: [],
        flowing: true,
        ended: true,
        endEmitted: true,
        reading: false,
        constructed: true,
        sync: true,
        needReadable: false,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        emitClose: true,
        autoDestroy: true,
        destroyed: true,
        errored: null,
        closed: true,
        closeEmitted: true,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        awaitDrainWriters: null,
        multiAwaitDrain: false,
        readingMore: true,
        dataEmitted: true,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null,
        [Symbol(kPaused)]: false
      },
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {
        end: [ [Function: responseOnEnd], [Function: handleStreamEnd] ],
        error: [Function: handleStreamError],
        data: [Function: handleStreamData],
        aborted: [Function: handlerStreamAborted]
      },
      _eventsCount: 4,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      socket: <ref *2> Socket {
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'localhost',
        _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
        _readableState: ReadableState {
          objectMode: false,
          highWaterMark: 16384,
          buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
          length: 0,
          pipes: [],
          flowing: true,
          ended: false,
          endEmitted: false,
          reading: true,
          constructed: true,
          sync: false,
          needReadable: true,
          emittedReadable: false,
          readableListening: false,
          resumeScheduled: false,
          errorEmitted: false,
          emitClose: false,
          autoDestroy: true,
          destroyed: false,
          errored: null,
          closed: false,
          closeEmitted: false,
          defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
          awaitDrainWriters: null,
          multiAwaitDrain: false,
          readingMore: false,
          dataEmitted: true,
          decoder: null,
          encoding: null,
          [Symbol(kPaused)]: false
        },
        _events: [Object: null prototype] {
          end: [Function: onReadableStreamEnd],
          free: [Function: onFree],
          close: [ [Function: onClose], [Function: socketCloseListener] ],
          timeout: [Function: onTimeout],
          agentRemove: [Function: onRemove],
          error: [Function: socketErrorListener],
          finish: [Function: bound onceWrapper] {
            listener: [Function: destroy]
          }
        },
        _eventsCount: 7,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: WritableState {
          objectMode: false,
          highWaterMark: 16384,
          finalCalled: true,
          needDrain: false,
          ending: true,
          ended: true,
          finished: false,
          destroyed: false,
          decodeStrings: false,
          defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
          length: 0,
          writing: false,
          corked: 0,
          sync: false,
          bufferProcessing: false,
          onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
          writecb: null,
          writelen: 0,
          afterWriteTickInfo: null,
          buffered: [],
          bufferedIndex: 0,
          allBuffers: true,
          allNoop: true,
          pendingcb: 1,
          constructed: true,
          prefinished: false,
          errorEmitted: false,
          emitClose: false,
          autoDestroy: true,
          errored: null,
          closed: false,
          closeEmitted: false,
          [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
        },
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: null,
        _server: null,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Circular *1],
        [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 969,
        [Symbol(kHandle)]: TCP {
          reading: true,
          onconnection: null,
          [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *2]
        },
        [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
        [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
        [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
        [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
        [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
        [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
        [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: true,
        [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: true,
        [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 60,
        [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
        [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
      },
      httpVersionMajor: 1,
      httpVersionMinor: 1,
      httpVersion: '1.1',
      complete: true,
      rawHeaders: [
        'date',
        'Fri, 06 Dec 2024 19:03:51 GMT',
        'server',
        'uvicorn',
        'content-type',
        'text/html; charset=utf-8',
        'x-frame-options',
        'DENY',
        'content-length',
        '3092',
        'vary',
        'origin',
        'x-content-type-options',
        'nosniff',
        'referrer-policy',
        'same-origin',
        'connection',
        'close'
      ],
      rawTrailers: [],
      aborted: false,
      upgrade: false,
      url: '',
      method: null,
      statusCode: 403,
      statusMessage: 'Forbidden',
      client: <ref *2> Socket {
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'localhost',
        _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
        _readableState: ReadableState {
          objectMode: false,
          highWaterMark: 16384,
          buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
          length: 0,
          pipes: [],
          flowing: true,
          ended: false,
          endEmitted: false,
          reading: true,
          constructed: true,
          sync: false,
          needReadable: true,
          emittedReadable: false,
          readableListening: false,
          resumeScheduled: false,
          errorEmitted: false,
          emitClose: false,
          autoDestroy: true,
          destroyed: false,
          errored: null,
          closed: false,
          closeEmitted: false,
          defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
          awaitDrainWriters: null,
          multiAwaitDrain: false,
          readingMore: false,
          dataEmitted: true,
          decoder: null,
          encoding: null,
          [Symbol(kPaused)]: false
        },
        _events: [Object: null prototype] {
          end: [Function: onReadableStreamEnd],
          free: [Function: onFree],
          close: [ [Function: onClose], [Function: socketCloseListener] ],
          timeout: [Function: onTimeout],
          agentRemove: [Function: onRemove],
          error: [Function: socketErrorListener],
          finish: [Function: bound onceWrapper] {
            listener: [Function: destroy]
          }
        },
        _eventsCount: 7,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: WritableState {
          objectMode: false,
          highWaterMark: 16384,
          finalCalled: true,
          needDrain: false,
          ending: true,
          ended: true,
          finished: false,
          destroyed: false,
          decodeStrings: false,
          defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
          length: 0,
          writing: false,
          corked: 0,
          sync: false,
          bufferProcessing: false,
          onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
          writecb: null,
          writelen: 0,
          afterWriteTickInfo: null,
          buffered: [],
          bufferedIndex: 0,
          allBuffers: true,
          allNoop: true,
          pendingcb: 1,
          constructed: true,
          prefinished: false,
          errorEmitted: false,
          emitClose: false,
          autoDestroy: true,
          errored: null,
          closed: false,
          closeEmitted: false,
          [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
        },
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: null,
        _server: null,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Circular *1],
        [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 969,
        [Symbol(kHandle)]: TCP {
          reading: true,
          onconnection: null,
          [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *2]
        },
        [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
        [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
        [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
        [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
        [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
        [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
        [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: true,
        [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: true,
        [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 60,
        [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
        [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
      },
      _consuming: false,
      _dumped: false,
      req: [Circular *1],
      responseUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/login/',
      redirects: [],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kHeaders)]: {
        date: 'Fri, 06 Dec 2024 19:03:51 GMT',
        server: 'uvicorn',
        'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
        'x-frame-options': 'DENY',
        'content-length': '3092',
        vary: 'origin',
        'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
        'referrer-policy': 'same-origin',
        connection: 'close'
      },
      [Symbol(kHeadersCount)]: 18,
      [Symbol(kTrailers)]: null,
      [Symbol(kTrailersCount)]: 0
    },
    aborted: false,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: null,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    reusedSocket: false,
    host: 'localhost',
    protocol: 'http:',
    _redirectable: Writable {
      _writableState: WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        finalCalled: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        destroyed: false,
        decodeStrings: true,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: true,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        afterWriteTickInfo: null,
        buffered: [],
        bufferedIndex: 0,
        allBuffers: true,
        allNoop: true,
        pendingcb: 0,
        constructed: true,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        emitClose: true,
        autoDestroy: true,
        errored: null,
        closed: false,
        closeEmitted: false,
        [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
      },
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {
        response: [Function: handleResponse],
        error: [Function: handleRequestError],
        socket: [Function: handleRequestSocket]
      },
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _options: {
        maxRedirects: 21,
        maxBodyLength: Infinity,
        protocol: 'http:',
        path: '/login/',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: [Object: null prototype] {
          Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'X-CSRFToken': '9aSiDra8P3LzU0hMlSFZ9yqX5fllDySQljBRyHM6jjSYfuZ1BWrCUF9blkElzl1v',
          'User-Agent': 'axios/1.7.9',
          'Content-Length': '42',
          'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, compress, deflate, br'
        },
        agents: { http: undefined, https: undefined },
        auth: undefined,
        family: undefined,
        beforeRedirect: [Function: dispatchBeforeRedirect],
        beforeRedirects: { proxy: [Function: beforeRedirect] },
        hostname: 'localhost',
        port: '8000',
        agent: undefined,
        nativeProtocols: {
          'http:': {
            _connectionListener: [Function: connectionListener],
            METHODS: [Array],
            STATUS_CODES: [Object],
            Agent: [Function],
            ClientRequest: [Function: ClientRequest],
            IncomingMessage: [Function: IncomingMessage],
            OutgoingMessage: [Function: OutgoingMessage],
            Server: [Function: Server],
            ServerResponse: [Function: ServerResponse],
            createServer: [Function: createServer],
            validateHeaderName: [Function: __node_internal_],
            validateHeaderValue: [Function: __node_internal_],
            get: [Function: get],
            request: [Function: request],
            setMaxIdleHTTPParsers: [Function: setMaxIdleHTTPParsers],
            maxHeaderSize: [Getter],
            globalAgent: [Getter/Setter]
          },
          'https:': {
            Agent: [Function: Agent],
            globalAgent: [Agent],
            Server: [Function: Server],
            createServer: [Function: createServer],
            get: [Function: get],
            request: [Function: request]
          }
        },
        pathname: '/login/'
      },
      _ended: true,
      _ending: true,
      _redirectCount: 0,
      _redirects: [],
      _requestBodyLength: 42,
      _requestBodyBuffers: [],
      _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
      _currentRequest: [Circular *1],
      _currentUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/login/',
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    }, 
    .
    .
    .
    data: '\n' +
      '<!DOCTYPE html>\n' +
      '<html lang="en">\n' +
      '<head>\n' +
      '  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">\n' +
      '  <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE">\n' +
      '  <title>403 Forbidden</title>\n' +
      '  <style type="text/css">\n' +
      '    html * { padding:0; margin:0; }\n' +
      '    body * { padding:10px 20px; }\n' +
      '    body * * { padding:0; }\n' +
      '    body { font:small sans-serif; background:#eee; color:#000; }\n' +
      '    body>div { border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; }\n' +
      '    h1 { font-weight:normal; margin-bottom:.4em; }\n' +
      '    h1 span { font-size:60%; color:#666; font-weight:normal; }\n' +
      '    #info { background:#f6f6f6; }\n' +
      '    #info ul { margin: 0.5em 4em; }\n' +
      '    #info p, #summary p { padding-top:10px; }\n' +
      '    #summary { background: #ffc; }\n' +
      '    #explanation { background:#eee; border-bottom: 0px none; }\n' +
      '  </style>\n' +
      '</head>\n' +
      '<body>\n' +
      '<div id="summary">\n' +
      '  <h1>アクセス禁止 <span>(403)</span></h1>\n' +
      '  <p>CSRF検証に失敗したため、リクエストは中断されました。</p>\n' +
      '\n' +
      '\n' +
      '  <p>このメッセージが表示されている理由は、このサイトはフォーム送信時にCSRFクッキーを必須としているためです。このクッキーはセキュリティ上の理由(使用中のブラウザが第三者によってハイジャックされていないことを確認するため)で必要です。</p>\n' +
      '  <p>もしブラウザのクッキーを無効に設定しているならば、same-originリクエストのために少なくともこのサイトでは再度有効にしてください。</p>\n' +
      '\n' +
      '</div>\n' +
      '\n' +
      '<div id="info">\n' +
      '  <h2>Help</h2>\n' +
      '    \n' +
      '    <p>Reason given for failure:</p>\n' +
      '    <pre>\n' +
      '    CSRF cookie not set.\n' +
      '    </pre>\n' +
      '    \n' +
      '\n' +
      '  <p>In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when\n' +
      '  <a\n' +
      '  href="https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/csrf/">Django’s\n' +
      '  CSRF mechanism</a> has not been used correctly.  For POST forms, you need to\n' +
      '  ensure:</p>\n' +
      '\n' +
      '  <ul>\n' +
      '    <li>Your browser is accepting cookies.</li>\n' +
      '\n' +
      '    <li>The view function passes a <code>request</code> to the template’s <a\n' +
      '    href="https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.base.Template.render"><code>render</code></a>\n' +
      '    method.</li>\n' +
      '\n' +
      '    <li>In the template, there is a <code>{% csrf_token\n' +
      '    %}</code> template tag inside each POST form that\n' +
      '    targets an internal URL.</li>\n' +
      '\n' +
      '    <li>If you are not using <code>CsrfViewMiddleware</code>, then you must use\n' +
      '    <code>csrf_protect</code> on any views that use the <code>csrf_token</code>\n' +
      '    template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.</li>\n' +
      '\n' +
      '    <li>The form has a valid CSRF token. After logging in in another browser\n' +
      '    tab or hitting the back button after a login, you may need to reload the\n' +
      '    page with the form, because the token is rotated after a login.</li>\n' +
      '  </ul>\n' +
      '\n' +
      '  <p>You’re seeing the help section of this page because you have <code>DEBUG =\n' +
      '  True</code> in your Django settings file. Change that to <code>False</code>,\n' +
      '  and only the initial error message will be displayed.  </p>\n' +
      '\n' +
      '  <p>You can customize this page using the CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW setting.</p>\n' +
      '</div>\n' +
      '\n' +
      '</body>\n' +
      '</html>\n'
  },
  status: 403
}

